# How to build RESTful API for partly updating large resource

Tags: http, rest, spring-mvc

I'm building an ordering service and stuck on the update scenarios.

I have exposed an POST URI for placing orders:

```
Request:
POST /orders
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
```

Assume that the order contains a lot of infomation. For example, there is two remarks for the order, one for the customer and one for the staff. How can I build RESTfule api for update them? Here are potential solutions occurred to me:

**A. Client retrieve the entire order representation and use PUT/POST to update the whole resource**

1.When the customer want to modify the customer remark, use

```
GET /orders/{orderId}
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
```

to retrieve the order resource on the client side:

```
{orderId:1234,
 ............,
 customerRemark:'Red color is prefered',
 staffRemark:'Some internal business process tips'}
```

2. Update the order resource on the client and then post/put it using:

```
 POST/PUT /orders/{orderId}
 Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
 BODY:{order represenetation modified}
```

But this is kind of unconvenient because the client updating the customer remark(a b2c website) doesn't care about the staff remark(which is a concern of a backoffice system) and vice versa.

**B.Split into smaller resources**

1.Split customer remark and staff remark as individual sub-resource of order:

```
GET /orders/{orderId}/remark/customer
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999    

GET /orders/{orderId}/remark/Staff
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
```

2.Use POST/PUT to update them seperately:

```
PUT /orders/{orderId}/remark/customer
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999    

PUT /orders/{orderId}/remark/Staff
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
```

This solution could use full advantage of HTTP verbs （i.e.  use DELETE if customer wants to remove the remark）, but it's also kind of weired because remark is not an entity but just a value in the domain.

Which one is better? Or is there other solutions available?

Answer (score 1):

There's an HTTP verb [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) which is useful in this scenario.

If you want to stick with the more common verbs, do a POST to `/orders/{orderId}`.  It is true that, if you follow the intent of HTTP, you should only use PUT for complete resource replacement.  You can do pretty much whatever you want when POSTing to a resource, so it *can* be used for partial updates.

Go with the sub-resources if they are meaningful to your application, rather than just a convenient hack for partial updating.

Comment: Can I update different part of the resource with same URI using PATCH?

Comment: Yes, the common usage pattern is to supply a JSON (or XML) document in the body of the PATCH request and the server is supposed to only update the fields appearing in that document.

Comment: Do I have to extract the body attribute manually? It seems that few main-framework supports mapping JSON to a dynamic Class. Is there some utility in JAVA platform or Spring MVC specicially?

Comment: If by dynamic class you mean a class created on the fly then I'm not aware of any such facility in Java.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself well. I mean do I have to iterate the @RequestBody( a POJO contains all potential attributes)‘s attributes one by one to check if they're absent(by checking null values)? The update code will easily becomes boring like " if request.remark !=null order.update(request.remark);"

Comment: Oh, I see.  According to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731989/partial-bean-serialization-and-deserializationmerging) it would appear that Jackson has support for this.  I have not tried it, though, but it looks very simple.  If it doesn't work, you can implement your own partial updater (using reflection or bean utils, say) and contribute as open source.